# IIS Url Rewrite help - Redirect root with Query Parametr

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have a website `example.com`

I have the website split on two different servers, Front End HTML in many locations around the world.

When I goto `example.com\?` or `example.com\?1231` I want to re-direct it to `example.com`

But I don't want to redirect `example.com\backend\?test=1`

How do I get this accomplished, I tried a few different things and failed miserably.

It's the only scenario I can't get to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
                <rule name="Remove Request" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="*" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="off" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_HOST}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

I think the above should work as a URL Rewrite. Tested on a site I have.